# UITextField with auto wrapping

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I am trying to make UITextField with auto text wrapping, but I can't do it.

Comment: This link has the answer for your question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979661/uitextfield-rigtht-frame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use UITextView much easier
http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html

Comment: But I can't show keyboard, if I'am using UITextView. I want to make commenting to my site.

Comment: dear itruf, keyboard will always be there even if you use a UITextView